# How to save lines from a file into an array

Tags: c++, file

I want to get lines from a .txt file and save it into an array. Then I want to display it in a for loop. Here is my code and I don't know what is wrong with it. My file is named quiz.

The program is running but it doesn't display array with lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream quiz;
    quiz.open("quiz.txt", ios::in);

    if(quiz.good()==false)
    {
        cout<<"File does not exist"; exit(0);
    }

    string array[100000];
    string one;
    int counter=0;

    while(getline(quiz,one))
    {

        one=array[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=counter; i++)
    {
        cout<<array[i];
    }

    quiz.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `array[counter] = one` instead of `one = array[counter]`

Comment: VTC as being a simple typo (`one=array[counter];` instead of `array[counter] = one;`).

Comment: _"Programm is working but it doesn't display array with lines."_ Then it's not _working_, no?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.